# Content-length in php file_get_content post request

Tags: php, google-data-api

I am trying to update Google fussion table through a php post request. URL works perfectly fine on [Auth PlayGround](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). See the image below. Sorry! Stack overflow is not allowing me to post image, please use this link [Image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwxnPrGJ8UfOd3dMWHZpMF9ISHM/edit?pli=1)

But when I try the same using php post request file_get_content, it shoots with an error "411 Length Required". What length is the code asking for. Obviously its not content length because its "Zero" in this case.

```
<?php
$url = https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT INTO 1f_Z_********bQ-br8g17rFWBknri03fz-EQc (Name, Phone) VALUES ('Anees Hameed', '9895435751')
$Post = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'header'  => 'GData Version: 3.0',
        'header'  => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$_Session[access_token]
    )
);
$Post= stream_context_create($Post);
$request = file_get_content($url, false, $Post);
?>
```

How to get rid of this error.

Comment: Use `curl` instead of `file_get_content`.

Comment: curl is not allowed..I am using Google App Engine where curl is not allowed :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all what's that URL in your code?! and you didn't wrapped it within quotes either.

> 411 error
>
> This error seldom occurs in most Web traffic, particularly when the
>   client system is a Web browser. The problem can only be resolved by
>   examining what your client system is trying to do then discussing with
>   your ISP why the Web server expects a 'Content-Length' specification.

and your code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/";
$content = "this is something to be sent to the server";
$Post = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'header'  => 'GData Version: 3.0',
        'header'  => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$_Session[access_token],
        'header'  => 'Content-Length: '.strlen($content)
    )
);
$Post= stream_context_create($Post);
$request = file_get_content($url, false, $Post);
?>
```

Comment: Opps I missed to put quotes, Url is same ** $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT INTO 1f_Z_********bQ-br8g17rFWBknri03fz-EQc (Name, Phone) VALUES ('Anees Hameed', '9895435751')"; ** This works perfect in the Google [Auth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).... There is no Body contents in this request, everything is send through url as post request and hence no Content-length.

Comment: @AneesHameed you should send a sample content to see the behavior of the server.

Comment: @revo- I will check with urlencode. What do you mean by send a sample content to server and check it behavior.

Comment: @All: How abt using an header like this 
$post= array('http' =>
    array(
        'ignore_errors' => '1'
         ));
is it going to make any difference...

Comment: Yep, I tried it already, but its not working. Says that the same error "411 Length Required". I dont know what length are they asking for. :)